# Mac OS local proxy, connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3000

Tags: macos, networking, proxy, http-proxy

I have a create-react-app app running on `localhost:3000` and a proxy server running on `localhost:4000` that redirects some of my request to port 3000.

Requesting `localhost:3000/` correctly returns index.html file,

Requesting `localhost:4000/` returns `connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3000` with 502 code.

The exact same setup works properly on Ubuntu (returns index.html from localhost:4000) and Windows so I am sure proxy works fine.

Proxy is built using https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy but i was unable to find any solution to this in documentation.

My question is: Does mac require changing some extra settings to allow this kind of traffic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to edit `/etc/hosts` and remove `::1 localhost` mapping or change it to `::1 ip6-localhost` (default setting on ubuntu)

Comment: Is there any danger in removing the ::1 configuration?